# Publishing Aspnet Core Angular Cli project on Amazon Aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, asp.net-core, angular-cli, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Aspnet Core project and Angular Cli on project that works on wwwroot of Aspnet Core project. I need to publish this website Amazon Aws.
By following the steps of tutorial of publishing Aspnet Core on Amazon Aws Elastic beans does not help. I get full of errors. There is also tutorial for publishing angular on Amaon Aws S3. I need to combine them in order to get my project published. Anybody can help me?